# Run regex rule for outlook 365

Tags: .net, plugins, outlook, office365

I want to run a regex based rule for outlook 365.
I saw that I can do this for [outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007)

But is it possible to do this also for outlook 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are referring to is based on the VBA macro call where regular expressions are used. You can do the same for any offline Office edition, but not the web one. So, you can implement the same for Outlook 2013.